# http PUT method in python mechanize

Tags: python

I am using python mechanize lib and I am trying to use http PUT method on some url - but I cant find any option for this. I see only GET and POST methods...

If the PUT method is not working maybe some1 can tell me a better lib for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
class PutRequest(mechanize.Request):
  "Extend the mechanize Request class to allow a http PUT"
  def get_method(self):
    return "PUT"
```

You can then use this when making a request like this:

```
browser.open(PutRequest(url,data=your_encoded_params,headers=your_headers))
```

NOTE: I arrived at this solution by digging into the mechanize code packages to find out where mechanize was setting the HTTP method. I noticed that when we call `mechanize.Request`, we are using the Request class in `_request.py` which in turn is extending the Request class in `_urllib2_fork.py`. The http method is actually set in `get_method` of the Request class in `_urllib2_fork.py`. Turns out `get_method` in `_urllib2_fork.py` was allowing only GET and POST methods. To get past this limitation, I ended up writing my own put and delete classes that extended mechanize. Request but over-rode `get_method()` only.

Comment: You could include the source: http://qxf2.com/blog/python-mechanize-the-missing-manual/

Comment: @wernight - I wrote the source. So it is ok not include it ;)

Comment: Ha ha yes I guess it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#http-verbs):

```
>>> import requests
>>> result = requests.put("http://httpbin.org/put", data='hello')
>>> result.text
```

---

Per [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.put):

```
requests.put(url, data=None, **kwargs)
Sends a PUT request. Returns Response object.

Parameters: 
url – URL for the new Request object.
data – (optional) Dictionary or bytes to send in the body of the Request.
**kwargs – Optional arguments that request takes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Via [**Mechanize**](http://joesourcecode.com/Documentation/mechanize0.2.5/):

```
import mechanize
import json

class PutRequest(mechanize.Request):
  def get_method(self):
    return 'PUT'

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(
    PutRequest('http://example.com/',
    data=json.dumps({'locale': 'en'}),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}))
```

See also http://qxf2.com/blog/python-mechanize-the-missing-manual/ (probably outdated).

[**Requests**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#http-verbs) does it in a nicer way as [*Key Zhu* said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13810574/167897).